# ClassNotFoundException when trying to execute a jar

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm working on a project that allows me to easily read and edit a certain type of file from a sort of terminal. It uses two java files, Main.java and Word.java, which have both been compiled into .class files.

In the folder with my com folder, there is also a bin folder containing a manifest file and another com folder containing the class files.

Here's a sort of visualisation of the file paths:

```
com vvv
    Main.java
    Word.java
bin vvv
    MANIFEST.MF
    com vvv
        Main.class
        Word.class
```

The manifest file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.Main
Created-By: 19.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)
```

To compile it, I use the Visual Studio Code terminal and use the command `jar cvfm DictionaryParser.jar bin/MANIFEST.MF bin/com/Main.class bin/com/Word.class`

This successfully compiles it into a .jar file. However, whenever I run this jar file, using the command `java -jar DictionaryParser.jar`, it gives me this error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Main
```

No matter what I do, this error keeps coming up. Java cmd commands in general are really confusing to me, but I just don't get what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas? Am I just making a stupid mistake? Keep in mind I don't have much experience with Java compared to other programming languages, especially the JVM.

Comment: Did you declare `package com` in your `Main.java` file? Just putting the class file in the right folder is not enough. You should also check that the jar file actually contains the files in the right places. That's easy to do, it's just a zip file.

Comment: @Jorn I did declare ```package com```, and I checked the jar file, both class files are in the bin/com folder.

Comment: You have to specify something, otherwise the "bin" is going to be included in your jar folder structure. Check the output of `jar tf DictionaryParser.jar` I suspect you'll have the bin folder in there. `com` should be the root.

Comment: @matt Using ```jar tf DictionaryParser.jar``` gave me ```META-INF, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, bin/com/Main.class, bin/com/Word.class```. I'm not sure what you mean by com being the root (again, please excuse my Java inexperience). Also, how do I use ```-C``` to change the folder? What in the command do I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting your classes in the wrong folder. Here is an example.

This is the incorrect way.

> jar cf Test.jar junk/com/Broken.class

Which results in:

```
$jar tf Test.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
junk/com/Broken.class
```

See the folder structure is incorrect. The package should be the root folder.

The correct way.

> jar cf Test.jar -C junk com/Broken.class

Then the jar contains:

```
$jar tf Test.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/Broken.class
```